# How to change 'selection criterion' in Lotus notes Views

Tags: lotus-notes

I have  Lotus Notes Client and some Views created already. How can I see the 'Selection Creterion' for views, and I need to change 'Selection Creterion' also.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Open view in Designer and click beneath the column headers. "View Selection" should then be visible. There you can choose between "Simple Search" and "Formula" and enter/change your selections.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'Design Synopis' tool to produce a report of the design settings of most design elements, including view selection formulas.

Select the application/database, then, from the main menu, goto: File, Application, Design Synopsis and select 'Define contact, Views' and select which features you want. Choose 'selection formuals' and produce the report.

If you want to change selection formulas, either use the Domino Designer (as mentioned elewhere here) or create an agent that change the selection formula for you. Check the Desinger Help for details of how to do this programmatically.